# jQueryUI .sortable() needs to wake up; won't accept droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is a problem that was a real, prolonged nightmare for me. I am posting it here, to save someone else a real headache.

There is a **sortable()** and items that can be dropped into it. Everything works peachy, except that initially the **sortable()** won't accept items. Only after the user has changed the position of items within the **sortable()**, will the **sortable()** accept items.

In other words, it looks like the **.sortable()** needs to be waken up, before it will accept anything.

(It appears that [this poor soul](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-with-dragable) was struggling with the same problem. He never got any reply...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following transpired. My **.sortable()** was initialized with a **div style="display:none"**. This made perfect sense when I wrote it. When needed, the user simply pops up the **div** containing the **.sortable()**.

However, binding a **.sortable()** within a hidden **div** apparently causes it to sleep.

When I bind **.sortable()** with the **div** visible, everything is fine.

Hope this helps someone...